# Async POST fails on WP7 and F#

Tags: rest, asynchronous, f#, windows-phone

When I do `let! read = from.AsyncRead buf` in F#, it blocks and doesn't return until the TCP socket is dead. Why? And how do I fix it?

Its code:

```ml
module StreamUtil

open System.IO

/// copy from 'from' stream to 'toStream'
let (|>>) (from : Stream) (toStream : Stream) =
  let buf = Array.zeroCreate<byte> 1024
  let rec doBlock () =
    async {
      let! read = from.AsyncRead buf
      if read <= 0 then
        toStream.Flush()
        return ()
      else
        do! toStream.AsyncWrite(buf, 0, read)
        return! doBlock () }
  doBlock ()
```

It's being called from this code:

```ml
use fs = new FileStream(targPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
do! req.InputStream |>> fs
```

and requested over HTTP with this code from Windows Phone 7.1 emulator:

```
public void Send()
{
    var b = new UriBuilder(_imageService.BaseUrl) {Path = "/images"};

    var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(b.Uri);
    req.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    req.Method = "POST";
    var imgLen = SelectedImage.ImageStream.Length;
    req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = imgLen.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    req.Accept = "application/json";
    req.BeginGetRequestStream(RequestReady, new ReqState(req, imgLen));
}

void RequestReady(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var state = (ReqState)ar.AsyncState;
    var req = state.Request;

    var reqStream = req.EndGetRequestStream(ar);

    SmartDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(reqStream))
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(SelectedVoucher.ImageStream))
            {
                var readBytes = br.ReadBytes(state.ImgLen);

                // tried both 2
                sw.Write(readBytes);
                //sw.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(readBytes));
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
            req.BeginGetResponse(ResponseReady, req);
        });
}

// WHY IS IT YOU ARE NOT CALLED???
void ResponseReady(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);

        SmartDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                var msg = rdr.ReadToEnd();

                var imageLocation = response.Headers["Location"];

                Debug.WriteLine(msg);
                Debug.WriteLine(imageLocation);
            });
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Unsuccessfully. The `ResponseReady` callback is never reached.

Meanwhile, this code works excellent:

```ml
open System
open System.Net.Http // WebAPI nuget

let sync aw = Async.RunSynchronously aw

let postC<'a> (c : HttpClient) (r : Uri) (cont : HttpContent) =
  let response = sync <| Async.AwaitTask( c.PostAsync(r, cont) )
  let struc:'a = sync <| deserialize<'a> response
  response, struc

let withContent<'a> (fVerb : (HttpClient -> Uri -> HttpContent -> _ * 'a))=
  let c = new HttpClient()
  fVerb c

[<Test>]
let ``POST /images 201 + Location header`` () =
  let post = withContent<MyImage> postC
  let bytes = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("sample.jpg")
  let hash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(bytes) |> Convert.ToBase64String
  let pic = new ByteArrayContent(bytes)
  pic.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
  pic.Headers.Add("X-SHA1-Hash", hash)
  let resp, ri = (resource "/images", pic) ||> post

  resp.StatusCode =? Code.Created
  ri.sha1 =? hash
  mustHaveHeaders resp
```

I couldn't get Fiddler2 working with WP7.

**EDIT: Welcome to a yak. I've moved onto greener pastures myself ;)**

Comment: If `from.AsyncRead` blocks that means that remote server does not send any bytes.

Comment: I've gotten away from the problem that the stream doesn't close properly, but I'm still only getting files sized 40 bytes large on the receiving side and on WP a lot of operations that are blocking throw NotSupportedException instead of not being available, so it's really painful to debug. I'm going to post a complete solution when I arrive at it.

Comment: I haven't forgotten this question; just a lot to do right now, will post fix shortly.

Comment: This may be useful to you if you're trying to make fiddler work with mobile devices: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/11/09/using-fiddler-to-sniff-mobile-device-application-traffic

Comment: Nice tip Alpha! I will try that! (Reason for delay right now is vacation and a focus on getting a first customer demo of the desktop application out)

Comment: Isn't this expected behaviour when you request an infinite amount of bytes from a TCP socket?

Comment: I'm not, I'm requesting 1024 bytes from it.

Comment: This may be a dumb extra question in here, but should there be an "EndInvoke" on the SmartDispatcher.  I realize it is an annonmous method, but if end isn't called on Async stuff, alot of times (I have found) it just locks up till it is.

Comment: Oh, another WP7 problem. I'd try and get Fiddler2 working before anything.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx

I've got the Emulator working with Fiddler by following this guide without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

YOu should put the bytes into the before sending and using BufferStream INput output